# AVD not working even after installing haxm

Tags: android-studio

iam trying to run android studio on my laptop lenovo i7.it was successfully instelled . i createed virtual device successfully but it doesnt worked and i instelled haxm.Installation was success full but it yet not working showing the same error "x86 emulator currently needs hardware acceleration."

Comment: Have you turned on Virtualization in BIO settings? Please go through this: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration

Comment: Yes but its still not working